# Filling DateTime and Int gaps

Tags: entity-framework, list, datetime

I am counting posts by Month, by Day, or by Hour, using EF.

I end up with a list DateTime/Int where there are some DateTime gaps.

The gaps are in years, when counting by year, in months, when counting by month, ...

Is there a way to write an extension that fills DateTime gaps by year or month, ...

Or even another extension that fills int gaps?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your code, why don't you prepopulate your tables with all of the dates you require (i.e no gaps) with count of 0.

```
Date     Count
Jan2012  0
Feb2012  0
Mar2012  0
...
Dec2049  0
```

This will guarantee that your list will not ever have gaps.  You can script this generation with sql date functions or use Excel and import to the database.

Comment: This might seem hacky but I'd use exactly this solution. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I am doing is the following:

```
// Tupple to hold data
IList<Tuple<DateTime, Int32>> data = new List<Tuple<DateTime, Int32>>();

// Get data from repository (Count by year) and add to Tupple
_repository.Set<Post>()
.Where(x => x.Created >= start && x.Created <= end)
.GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Created.Year })
.Select(x => new { Year = x.Key.Year, Count = x.Count() })
.ToList().ForEach(x => data.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, Int32>(new DateTime(x.Year, 1, 1), x.Count)));

// Fill empty years with 0 as count
for (Int32 i = 0; i <= (end - start).TotalYears; i++)
  if (!data.Any(x => x.Item1 == start.AddYears(i)))
    data.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, Int32>(start.AddYears(i), 0));

// Resort data
data = data.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ToList();
```

Basically I was looking for a way to do this in less steps ...

Maybe using table Union or Join ...

I just fill I am using to many steps ...

Thank You,
Miguel